# could not get a field value by reflection getter of Topic.id

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly, stateless

Hello i have a RSSFEED with Maven and Jboss know i try to add Topics to a Newsfeed but i get this error:

```
14:02:43,526 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-10) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffc0a80185:737c90a9:552bae74:4b, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@694357 >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of Topic.id
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1882) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
```

I try to have a @ManytoMany with my Topic.java and News.Java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;



@Table(name = "Topic")
@Entity
public class Topic implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="seq_topic")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq_topic", sequenceName="seq_topic", allocationSize=1)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @ManyToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "topic")
    private List<News> News = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<News> getNews() {
        return News;
    }

    public void setNews(List<News> news) {
        News = news;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Topic(){

    }
    public Topic(String name){
        this.name =name;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Topic other = (Topic) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now I dont really now where ist the Problem because i Have a getter and Setter Methode !

Comment: I am running across the same problem. Were you able to fix this?